# How to extract column in a function

Tags: r

I wonder what code I should write to select a certain column in this code? I know there are other ways to calculated mean and sd in a dataset,this is just an example from a bigger dataset where I want to make this type of function to make graphs of several columns! The [i] is the problem, I also though it could be df[,i], but no. Any suggestions?

```
id <- rep(1:5, each=2)
trt <- c("A", "B")
trt <- rep(trt, 10)
q1 <- runif(10,0,1)
q2 <- runif(10,0,1)
q3 <- runif(10,0,1)

df <- data.frame(id,trt, q1,q2,q3)


test <- function (i){
  df <- df[df$trt %in% c("A"),[i]]
  dfm <- mean(df)
  dfsd <- sd(df)
  df <- data.frame(dfm,dfsd)
  return(df)
 }
test(4) #for example column number 4
```

Comment: Just a typo. It should be `df[df$trt %in% c("A"), i]`

Comment: Ahh yes of course, thanks!:) @Sotos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use :

```
test <- function (df, i){
  df <- df[df$trt == "A",i]
  return(data.frame(dfm = mean(df),dfsd = sd(df)))
}

test(df, 4)
#        dfm      dfsd
#1 0.4622674 0.3282482
```

**data**

```
set.seed(123)
id <- rep(1:5, each=2)
trt <- c("A", "B")
trt <- rep(trt, 10)
q1 <- runif(10,0,1)
q2 <- runif(10,0,1)
q3 <- runif(10,0,1)
df <- data.frame(id,trt, q1,q2,q3)
```